# How can a Domain Class cascade 'all-delete-orphan' to a child it has no reference to?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, all-delete-orphan

In Grails you can have a child class:

```
class Child {
    Father father
    static belongsTo = [Father, Mother]
}
```

With two parent classes

```
class Mother{
}

class Father { 
}
```

It appears that if I `father.delete()`, then Grails throws a database error saying that the `Father` can't be deleted because the `child` is still around.

**How do I cascade `all-delete-orphan` the *`Child`* if the *`Father`* class doesn't have a direct reference to the *`Child`* class?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it bi-directional using hasMany.

```
class Mother{
  static hasMany = Child
}
class Father{
  static hasMany = Child
}
```

Doing this should make the cascading work such that when you delete one of the parents the child will also be deleted.

Comment: Will this delete the `Father` if the `Child` is deleted because I'm trying to avoid that?

Comment: no it won't since a father to child is a one to many relationship, deleting a child will not delete the father.

Comment: Thanks for everything the one thing I'm having trouble with is how to do this with the hasMany map parameter.

Comment: If a child belongs to BOTH Father and Mother and if Father is deleted is there a way to prevent the child from being deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Peter Ledbrook has a good article that covered this
[GORM Gotchas Part 2](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/)

I couldn't get the belongsTo only part to work, but this works for me:

```
class Father {
  static hasMany = [children: Child]
}

class Child {
  static belongsTo = [father: Father]
}

void testDeleteItg() {
    def father = new Father().save()
    def child = new Child()
    father.addToChildren child
    child.save()
    def childId = child.id

    father.delete(flush:true)
    assertNull(Child.get(childId))
}
```

Comment: Will `static hasMany = Child` work in place of `static hasMany = [children: Child]`?